# Young adult novel about soldiers and crystals

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm trying to find this book I read a while ago.

- When these kids are sixteen, they change and they can use their magic.
- There are two breeds of soldiers who (on interbreeding) create a third powerful kind.
- The protagonist is one of these powerful ones capable of infusing crystals with her magic to fight.
- She wears contact lenses to hide that she is a mix-breed.

Comment: Which language/country did you read this in?

Comment: When was "a while ago". Five years, ten, thirty?

Comment: I don't think it's it, but the description reminds me a little of Joan D Vinge's [*Psion*](http://www.amazon.com/Psion-Cat-Joan-D-Vinge/dp/076530340X) , which has telepathic half-breeds with cat-like eyes and data-crystal miners.